# authentication methods for ESSO

Tags: ibm

I know that user can authenticate in Oracle ESSO via RFID,finger print recognition, smart cards and mobile phones. Does IBM Tivoli ESSO have support for authentication from NFC(android) and voice recognition? If yes then what are the necessary changes or drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it.  NFC is too bleeding edge, and Oracle is a bit of a dinosaur when it comes to modern technologies.  This is by no means definitive, and you really should ask the correct support channels from Oracle.